# How to use perl regex to modify Long Path

Tags: regex, perl, path, long-integer

Im trying to make a `perl` script that will go through a very long directory path `\dir1\dir2\dir3\.....\dir99`.

Im using `find` to go through that path.

Directory structure is something like this:

```
E:\work\important stuff\dir1
```

after I iterate it will go through `dir2` for eg

```
E:\work\important stuff\dir1\dir2
```

Im trying to write a `regex` that will replace what is between slashes `\` `\` with the name `a`. Purpose is to make the path shorter so I can then delete.

In the end the path will look like this:

```
E:\work\important stuff\a\a\a\....\a.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does only exist a branch of directories inside `important stuff`? I mean, only one directory `dir1`, and inside this only one, `dir2` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry that I didn't put the code in the 'code field'. It missed a backslash. Now it should be correct.

Try this?

```
$dir =~ s{[^\\]+}{a}g;
```